# sklearn Logistic Regression - Make prediction with custom input from outside testing data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, prediction

I'm doing Logistic Regression with sklearn to predict some categories given some descriptions. Here's the code at the moment

```
    X_Train, X_Test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['description'], df['category'])

    count_vect = CountVectorizer()
    X_Train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_Train)

    tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
    X_Train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_Train_counts)

    # Fit the logistic regression model
    clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, class_weight='balanced', solver='lbfgs', max_iter=1000)
    clf.fit(X_Train_tfidf, y_train)
```

To also manually check my predictions I do this

```
    # Make predictions
    predictions = clf.predict(tfidf_transformer.transform(count_vect.transform(X_Test)))

    print(X_Test.iloc[7])
    print(predictions[7])
```

My question is how can I make a prediction of a `category` by manually giving a custom `description` from outside the testing data (e.g. I manually input it)

If that's possible, is there also a way to get the top n predictions categories for that custom text?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
your_description = "some text"
vectorized = tfidf_transformer.transform(count_vect.transform([your_description]))
predictions = clf.predict(vectorized.reshape(-1, 1))
```